# Apache Superset 3.0.1 Sending Alert/Report in GMT TimeZone

Tags: celery, apache-superset, celerybeat, kombu

In Apache Superset 3.0.1, I want to scheduled Alert/Report and get the email in basis of GMT timezone. Currently, it is working on UTC format only.

Package Version
Apache Superset 3.0.1
Celery 5.3.5

Can you please help me how to change celery task checking in GMT format rather UTC.So, Superset Alert/Report will work on GMT timezone.

Currently ,in Apache Superset Alert/Report is working based on UTC Format only. I want to change this in GMT format